# Convert big file into binary code in perl

Tags: perl

I'm new in perl and trying to convert files into its binary code and save it as text file. I've learned that it can be done by using 'unpack' command. Unfortunately unpack only able to convert small file. Do perl can convert big file, say 1 GB into binary code? Any help will be much appreciate. Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $readFile = '/file directory';

open READ, $readFile or die "Cant open";
my $input = <READ>;
close READ;

# Convert file into binary code
my $bin = unpack 'B*',$input; 

# Display how much file were converted
print "\nRead ", length($bin)/8000000, ' Mbytes'; 

# Save the binary code into txt file
open(WRITE,">file.txt") or die "\nCan't create txt file";     
print WRITE "$bin";
close WRITE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it in chunks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

binmode STDOUT;

for $ARGV (@ARGV ? @ARGV : '-') {
   open(my $fh, $ARGV)
      or warn("Can't open $ARGV: $!\n"), next;

   binmode($fh);

   while (sysread($fh, my $buf, 64*1024)) {
      print(unpack('B*', $buf));
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
script file.in >file.out
```

Comment: @Miller, It really should, but it behaves as documented. Fixed. Also allowed file names to be passed as arguments as I had said should be done.

Comment: I noticed that you're doing an explicit `binmode`, which is undoubtedly good practice since it documents intent.  However, does that actually do anything for `sysread`?  I just did some windows testing and `sysread` automatically ignores `:crlf` translation, which makes sense logically.  I wouldn't want to trust default behavior, but I would assert that `sysread` *might* port without an explicit `binmode`.

Comment: @Miller, I was not aware that `sysread` disregarded :crlf. It's documented to obey :utf8 and :encoding (even though that would be very buggy), so no harm in making sure it doesn't obey :crlf too

Comment: I was just at a Perl Mongers meetup about [Cross Platform Perl](http://www.meetup.com/San-Francisco-Perl-Mongers/events/192858102/) on Tuesday, so yeah, `binmode` is a good idea for all platforms.  Anyway, thanks for cleaning up your post and the reminder about `-` for opening `STDIN`.  I'd forgotten that.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with large files because you're loading the entire file into memory.

I suggest you take advantage of a trick with `$/` as explained in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> Setting `$/` to a reference to an integer, scalar containing an integer, or scalar that's convertible to an integer will attempt to read records instead of lines, with the maximum record size being the referenced integer number of characters. So this:
>
> ```
>      1.     local $/ = \32768; # or \"32768", or \$var_containing_32768
>      2.     open my $fh, "<", $myfile or die $!;
>      3.     local $_ = <$fh>;
> ```
>
> will read a record of no more than `32768` characters from `$fh`.

Therefore the following script would work:

```
#!env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use open IO => ':raw';    # If called as: tobinary.pl infile.bin > out.txt

binmode(STDIN);           # If called as: tobinary.pl < infile.bin > out.txt
binmode(STDOUT);

local $/ = \(1<<16);

while (<>) {
    print unpack 'B*', $_;
}
```

Comment: I used `sysread` since it actually requests the size you provide from the system, while `read` and `readline` read a mere 4KB or 8KB at once from the system (depending on the version of Perl, no matter what size you specify). This makes it faster for large reads.

Comment: Anytime you're working with binary data, you want to make sure to use [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html).  The [`use open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) command I suggested was so that the `ARGV` filehandle would automatically use binmode as well.

Comment: Hi Miller. Really appreciate for the advice. Unfortunately, now I'm having "Out of memory" problem when saving the binary code into txt file. Is the "Out of memory" problem occur because txt can't handle huge size or it is because of my computer insufficient RAM capacity? Kindly please be advise that I'm trying to convert 1GB of mp4 file into binary code.